# Reactjs prevent unwanted renderings with useCallback and memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of `objects` called `data`. I loop this array and render the `Counter` component. Increment and decrement of the counter value are passed as props to the component.

But if I change the value in a one-component, the other two components also re-renders. Which is not needed. How do I prevent this behavior? I tried `memo` and `useCallback` but seems not implemented correctly.

**Counter.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

    const Counter = ({ value, onDecrement, onIncrement, id }) => {
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Function updated!", id);
      }, [onDecrement, onIncrement]);
      return (
        <div>
          {value}
          <button onClick={() => onDecrement(id)}>-</button>
          <button onClick={() => onIncrement(id)}>+</button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default React.memo(Counter);
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Counter from "../components/Counter";

export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      value: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      value: 0,
    },
  ]);

  const onIncrement = useCallback(
    (id) => {
      setData((e) =>
        e.map((record) => {
          if (record.id === id) {
            record.value += 1;
          }
          return record;
        })
      );
    },
    [data]
  );

  const onDecrement = useCallback(
    (id) => {
      setData((e) =>
        e.map((record) => {
          if (record.id === id) {
            record.value -= 1;
          }
          return record;
        })
      );
    },
    [data]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      {data.map((e) => {
        return (
          <Counter
            value={e.value}
            onDecrement={onDecrement}
            onIncrement={onIncrement}
            id={e.id}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: add key property to <Counter> and remove useCallback dependency

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `useCallback` & `useMemo` are not helpful in this case, since you're running an inline function in your render:

```
{data.map(e => <Counter ...>)}
```

This function will always returns a fresh array & the component will always be different than the previous one.

In order to fix this, I think you'd want to memoize that render function, not the Counter component.

Here's a simple memoized render function with useRef:

```
  // inside of a React component

  const cacheRef = useRef({})

  const renderCounters = (data) => {
    let results = []
    data.forEach(e => {
      const key = `${e.id}-${e.value}`
      const component = cacheRef.current[key] || <Counter
            value={e.value}
            key={e.id}
            onDecrement={onDecrement}
            onIncrement={onIncrement}
            id={e.id}
          />
      results.push(component)
      cacheRef.current[key] = component
    })

    return results
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      {renderCounters(data)}
    </div>
  );
```

In the codesandbox below, only the clicked component log its id:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-wildflower-0djo4?file=/src/App.js

**Disclaimer**: With this implementation, the component will only rerender if its data value changes. Other props (such as the increment/decrement callbacks) will not trigger changes. There's also no way to clear the cache.

Memoize is also trading memory for performance — sometimes it's not worth it. If there could be thousands of Counter, there're better optimiztion i.e. changing UI design, virtualizing the list, etc.

I'm sure there's a way to do this with `useMemo`/`React.memo` but I'm not familiar with it